# How to display Name, Thumbnail Image, Price, Add-to-cart Button On CMS PAGE?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, sku, thumbnail, name

I need to display all my products like,

```
Sku    Name Price    Thumbnail      Add-to-cart(Button)
```

How can i get all above details on CMS Page?

**Note : Add-To-Cart Error**

Comment: You need to call phtml from cms page and then you can use the php functions or magento's functions to get image, sku, name, price etc on cms page.

Comment: May i know the complete path, i mean where i can place my phtml file {{block type="core/template" template="templateFolder/file_name.phtml"}},

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below the screen shot

[image]

In order to get the below product collection in cms page Please First create

Cms page under below at admin side.

**Cms -> Pages -> Add New Page** -> under content

Please find the below screen shots

[image]

[image]

And place the Product collection content under the template file in mentioned

**file path: app/desgin/frontend/base/default/template/myphp/myphpcode.phtml**

Place the below code

```
<?php $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th class="prosku">Sku</th>
  <th class="proname">Name</th>
  <th class="proprice">Price</th>
  <th class="proimg">Thumbnail</th>
  <th class="pro-button">Add to Cart Button</th>
 </tr>
<?php 
    if(count($_productCollection)) {
        foreach($_productCollection as $product) {
?>
 <tr>
  <td class="prodsku"><?php echo $product->getSku(); ?></td>
  <td class="prodname"><?php echo $product->getName();?></td>
  <td class="prodprice"><?php echo $product->getPrice();?></td>
  <td class="prodimg"><img src="<?php echo $product->getImageUrl();?>" width="100px" height="100px"/></td>
  <td class="prod-add_to_Cart-button"><?php if($product->isSaleable()): ?>
   <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
   <?php else: ?>
   <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
   <?php endif; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
    }
?>
 </table>
<style type="text/css">
.prodsku, .prodname, .prodprice,  .prodimg, .prod-add_to_Cart-button{
    padding:10px;
}
.prosku, .proname, .proprice,  .proimg, .pro-button{
    padding:10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Everything okay,  but addtocart not working.

Comment: I will Check And Get back to you.

Comment: error is : ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0  in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Cmsmart\AjaxCart\controllers\IndexController.php on line 209

Comment: All are working, except Add-To-Cart.

Comment: <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart'] ?>   this one fatal error, can i get any help?